# Jquery - Passing event.data to .on() and .bind()

Tags: jquery, ajax

As I understand it, future versions on jQuery will not have `bind` so I am trying to use `on` instead. I have run into a problem though.

I am trying to understand why `bind` allows me to set `event.data` but `on` doesn't.

This works

```
$(document).bind('ajaxError', '#form-id', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
  $(event.data).render_form_errors($.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText));
});
```

This doesn't work

```
$(document).on('ajaxError', '#form-id', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
  $(event.data).render_form_errors($.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText));  
});
```

I have multiple forms on a single page so I am trying to render the error for each specific form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the second argument to [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a selector, not the event data (as `on()` is also meant to supersede [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)).

The correct syntax for `on()` in your case is:

```
$(document).on('ajaxError', null, '#form-id', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    $(event.data).render_form_errors($.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText));  
});
```

As an aside, note that, to my knowledge, no official source has said that *future versions of jQuery will not have `bind()`*. `on()` is indeed meant to supersede both `bind()` and `delegate()`, but neither method is deprecated and both will most probably remain around in the foreseeable future (there is a lot of code out there that still uses them).

Comment: I must have read wrong then, my mistake. But it is more correct to use `on()`?

Comment: Also, is their a way to determine from `.on('ajaxError'` which form caused this?

Comment: @Max, I'm afraid *more correct* is opinion-based :) It does centralize event binding and delegation in a single method, and it can be considered as more readable sometimes. Note that in your specific case, it forces you to specify a `null` selector, so your code actually *loses* readability somewhat. The root cause of the issue is the common case of calling `on("event", "selector", handler)` to perform event delegation. Taking the arguments the other way around in order to disambiguate `selector` from `data` would require us to specify `null` data at all times.